# Java Double.valueOf

Tags: java, jvm

At my work, all developer use [`Double.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(double)) instead of [`new Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)) constructor. In every case. For Integer or Short I can understand it for cache values but for not for `double` and `float`.

I look Double.valueOf [in OpenJDK sources](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Double.java) :

```
 /**
 * Returns a {@code Double} instance representing the specified
 * {@code double} value.
 * If a new {@code Double} instance is not required, this method
 * should generally be used in preference to the constructor
 * {@link #Double(double)}, as this method is likely to yield
 * significantly better space and time performance by caching
 * frequently requested values.
 *
 * @param  d a double value.
 * @return a {@code Double} instance representing {@code d}.
 * @since  1.5
 */
public static Double valueOf(double d) {
    return new Double(d);
}
```

So it just calls `Double`s constructor.
I can understand why the method exist for be coherent with Integer/Short...

But the comment on the method:

> this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor

After i see its the same comment on every `valueOf()` method. (Integer,Short ...)

The comment is false? Or an other process meddle?

I heard about intrinsic methods in Java, next step was search in hotspot code and in [vmSymbol.hpp](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp)

```
/* boxing methods: */                                                                                                 \
   do_name(    valueOf_name,              "valueOf")                                                                    \
  do_intrinsic(_Boolean_valueOf,          java_lang_Boolean,      valueOf_name, Boolean_valueOf_signature, F_S)         \
   do_name(     Boolean_valueOf_signature,                       "(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;")                              \
  do_intrinsic(_Byte_valueOf,             java_lang_Byte,         valueOf_name, Byte_valueOf_signature, F_S)            \
   do_name(     Byte_valueOf_signature,                          "(B)Ljava/lang/Byte;")                                 \
  do_intrinsic(_Character_valueOf,        java_lang_Character,    valueOf_name, Character_valueOf_signature, F_S)       \
   do_name(     Character_valueOf_signature,                     "(C)Ljava/lang/Character;")                            \
  do_intrinsic(_Short_valueOf,            java_lang_Short,        valueOf_name, Short_valueOf_signature, F_S)           \
   do_name(     Short_valueOf_signature,                         "(S)Ljava/lang/Short;")                                \
  do_intrinsic(_Integer_valueOf,          java_lang_Integer,      valueOf_name, Integer_valueOf_signature, F_S)         \
   do_name(     Integer_valueOf_signature,                       "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;")                              \
  do_intrinsic(_Long_valueOf,             java_lang_Long,         valueOf_name, Long_valueOf_signature, F_S)            \
   do_name(     Long_valueOf_signature,                          "(J)Ljava/lang/Long;")                                 \
  do_intrinsic(_Float_valueOf,            java_lang_Float,        valueOf_name, Float_valueOf_signature, F_S)           \
   do_name(     Float_valueOf_signature,                         "(F)Ljava/lang/Float;")                                \
  do_intrinsic(_Double_valueOf,           java_lang_Double,       valueOf_name, Double_valueOf_signature, F_S)          \
   do_name(     Double_valueOf_signature,                        "(D)Ljava/lang/Double;")
```

So after I grep `Double.valueOf` in source and I found [withebox.cpp](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/whitebox.cpp)

```
static jobject doubleBox(JavaThread* thread, JNIEnv* env, jdouble value) {
  return box(thread, env, vmSymbols::java_lang_Double(), vmSymbols::Double_valueOf_signature(), value);
}
```

and box method code :

```
template <typename T>
static jobject box(JavaThread* thread, JNIEnv* env, Symbol* name, Symbol* sig, T value) {
  ResourceMark rm(thread);
  jclass clazz = env->FindClass(name->as_C_string());
  CHECK_JNI_EXCEPTION_(env, NULL);
  jmethodID methodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz,
        vmSymbols::valueOf_name()->as_C_string(),
        sig->as_C_string());
  CHECK_JNI_EXCEPTION_(env, NULL);
  jobject result = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(clazz, methodID, value);
  CHECK_JNI_EXCEPTION_(env, NULL);
  return result;
}
```

and this code ...

Ok, I'm not advanced yet. This method box() is really called in server mode?

3 questions for resume :D

1. JVM intercept `Double.valueOf()` for call this box method?
2. `Double.valueOf` doesn't use JDK source and dont do a `new Double()`?
3. The comment on `Double.valueOf()` is just a dump copy/paste, `Double.valueOf` and `new Double` have same effect?

Comment: From the docs: "*If a new Double instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Double(double), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values*" - `valueOf` allows reusing of values. Yes, there is another process "meddling", a flyweight system, where objects of the same value are reused (not all values; typically within the range of byte) rather than constructing new objects.

Comment: If you're curious as to why `valueOf` is simply `new Double`, that's because `Double#valueOf` has an [intrinsic method](https://gist.github.com/apangin/7a9b7062a4bd0cd41fcc) which is typically used at runtime. However, there must be a default implementation for if such optimizations are disabled. Returning a `new Double` is the default implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do java intrinsic functions still have code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041036/why-do-java-intrinsic-functions-still-have-code)

Answer (score 11):

1. `Integer(int)`, `Double(double)` and similar constructors are deprecated (yes, they are actually marked as `@Deprecated`) since Java 9 as a part of [JEP 277](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/277).

   The [deprecation comment](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/1e249ca8d585/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Double.java#l603) tells that

   > The static factory `valueOf(double)` is generally a better choice, as it is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance.

   Although OpenJDK currently does not cache boxed doubles, static factory method opens a path for future optimizations. If it is decided to improve autoboxing of doubles either in the JVM or in the class library, applications will automatically benefit from the optimization without any changes from user side.
2. Another reason is that `Double.valueOf` is indeed an intrinsic method in HotSpot. The JVM [knows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/1e249ca8d585/src/hotspot/share/ci/ciMethod.cpp#l1316) about autoboxing methods, and uses this knowledge in [EliminateAutoBox](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/1e249ca8d585/src/hotspot/share/opto/c2_globals.hpp#l501) optimization.

   There are two related optimizations: EliminateAllocations and EliminateAutoBox. Even though they are both provided by Escape Analysis and look similar, they are applied in slightly different contexts, so it may happen that one optimization works, when the other does not, or vice versa.

   When autoboxing elimination succeeds, e.g. when JIT compiler discovers matching `valueOf` and `doubleValue` calls, and the object does not escape, the optimizer gets rid of both calls altogether.

   BTW, the mentioned [Whitebox](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/The+WhiteBox+testing+API) code is irrelevant. It is not used other than for internal HotSpot testing purposes.
3. The project [Valhalla](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/valhalla/Main), which is in active development now, leads to entire rethinking of primitive wrappers.

   The [current idea](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Ebriangoetz/valhalla/sov/02-object-model.html) is to make `int`, `double`, etc. [inline types](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/valhalla/LW2), with `Integer` and `Double` their reference projections. As a migration step, `Integer` and `Double` will become sealed abstract classes, hence there will be no way to instantiate them via constructors.

   So, consider deprecation of constructors as an intermediate step to the project Valhalla. By encouraging usage of factory methods, JDK developers clear a way for many optimizations they can do under the hood, including inlining `Double` instances wherever is possible.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer: ***Consistency***.

It is a concept you should strive for when coding, because it reduces the chance of errors, and makes the code easier to read.

---

Besides, you never know what optimizations might be added *at any time*, so use the `valueOf()` method unless you *require* a new `Double` value (which is extremely rare). Just because it doesn't cache common values *right now*, doesn't mean it won't in the future, or in a different implementation.

That is a concept called [***future-proofing***](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/79586/202153), which is also something you should strive for when coding.